# Partial out all but i-th variable in variadic function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm starting out learning Clojure, and was trying to implement some basic numerical derivative functions for practice. I'm trying to create a `gradient` function that accepts an n-variable function and the points at which to evaluate it. To do this in a "functional" style, I want to implement the gradient as a `map` of a 1-variable derivatives.

The 1-variable derivative function is simple:

```
(defn derivative 
"Numerical derivative of a univariate function."
[f x]
    (let [eps 10e-6] ; Fix epsilon, just for starters.
          ; Centered derivative is [f(x+e) - f(x-e)] / (2e)
          (/ (- (f (+ x eps)) (f (- x eps))) (* 2 eps))))
```

I'd like to design the gradient along these lines:

```
(defn gradient
"Numerical gradient of a multivariate function."
[f & x]
    (let [varity-index          (range (count x))
        univariate-in-i (fn [i] (_?_))] ; Creates a univariate fn
                                         ; of x_i (other x's fixed)
        ;; For each i = 0, ... n-1:
        ;; (1) Get univariate function of x_i
        ;; (2) Take derivative of that function
        ;; Gradient is sequence of those univariate derivatives.

        (map derivative (map univariate-in-i varity-index) x)))
```

So, `gradient` has variable arity (can accept any # of x's), and the order of the x's counts. The function `univariate-in-i` takes an index `i = 0, 1, ... n-1` and returns a 1-variable function by partial-ing out all the variables except `x_i`. E.g., you'd get:

```
#(f x_0 x_1 ... x_i-1 % x_i+1 ... x_n)
                      ^
                     (x_i still variable)
```

`map`-ping this function over `varity-index` gets you a sequence of 1-variable functions in each `x_i`, and then `map`-ping `derivative` over these gets you a sequence of derivatives in each `x_i` which is the gradient we want.

My questions is: I'm not sure what a good way to implement `univariate-in-i` is. I essentially need to fill in values for x's in `f` except at some particular spot (i.e., place the `%` above), but programmatically.

I'm more interested in technique than solution (i.e., I know how to compute gradients, I'm trying to learn functional programming and idiomatic Clojure). Therefore, I'd like to stay true to the strategy of treating the gradient as a map of 1-d derivatives over partialed-out functions. But if there's a better "functional" approach to this, please let me know. I'd rather not resort to macros if possible.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Using Ankur's answer below, the gradient function I get is:

```
(defn gradient
"Numerical gradient of a multivariate function."
[f & x]
    (let [varity-index     (range (count x))
          x-vec            (vec x)
          univariate-in-i 
             (fn [i] #(->> (assoc x-vec i %) (apply f)))]

       (map derivative (map univariate-in-i varity-index) x)))
```

which does exactly what I'd hoped, and seems very concise and functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `univariate-in-i` as shown below. (Assuming that all the other position values are defined in some var default which is a vector)

```
(fn [i] #(->>
           (assoc default i %)
           (apply f)))
```

Comment: `default` here would just be the `x` rest argument above, right?

Comment: This works great: `default` is `x`, but wrapped in a vector  It's a little to subtle for me to completely understand, but I'll think through it. I think this is the answer I'm looking for though. Thanks!

Comment: The trick is that vectors implement `clojure.lang.Associative`, which is what allows you to swap out the element at `i` for the unapplied argument :)

Answer (score 0):

if you find this abit difficult to comprehend (in the context of how to implement gradient), another variant of multivariable gradient implementation using clojure:
[image]
then, given `f and vector v of a1,....,aN`, will differentiate while all the variables except xi are fixed:

```
(defn partial-diff [f v i]
  (let [h 10e-6
        w (update v i + h)]
    (/ (- (apply f w) (apply f v))
       h)))

(defn gradient [f v]
  (map #(partial-diff f v %) (range (count v))))
```

=>

```
(gradient (fn [x y] 
              (+ (* x x) (* x y y))) [3 3])
=> (15.000009999965867 18.000030000564493)
```